# Inserting Data into MySQL Database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database on a web server which contains the columns idPlayers, First Name, Surname, Age, and Height. The user inputs the data in text boxes on a form and clicks a button to insert the data into the database, which already has several rows of data. Below is my code:

Method in Connection.cs Class:

```
public string AddPlayer(int idPlayers, string FirstName, string Surname, int Age, int Height)
    {
        string result;
        using (var Connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {

            Connection.Open();

                using (var command = new MySqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO Players(idPlayers, First Name, Surname, Age, Height) VALUES(@idPlayers, @First Name, @Surname, @Age, @Height)", Connection))
                    try
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("idPlayers", idPlayers);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("First Name", FirstName);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", Surname);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Age", Age);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Height", Height);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Connection.Close();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        result = "Failure";
                        return result;
                    }                    
            }
        result = "Success";
        return result;  
        }       
    }
```

Method call in Form1.cs Class

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result1;
        int idPlayers = 3;
        String FirstName = FirstNameBox.Text;
        String Surname = SurnameBox.Text;
        int Age = Convert.ToInt32(AgeBox.Text);
        int Height = Convert.ToInt32(HeightBox.Text);

        Connection NewCon = new Connection();
        result1 = NewCon.AddPlayer(idPlayers, FirstName, Surname, Age, Height);
        MessageBox.Show(result1);

    }
```

When I click the button to insert the data the message box displays Failure. Do you have any ideas why the data won't insert? The ConnectionString is definitely correct as I can read from the database elsewhere in my program.

Thanks for your help,
George

Amended Connection.cs class:

```
public string AddPlayer(int idPlayers, string FirstName, string Surname, int Age, int Height)
    {
        string result;
        using (var Connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {

            Connection.Open();

                using (var command = new MySqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO Players(idPlayers, First Name, Surname, Age, Height) VALUES(@idPlayers, @FirstName, @Surname, @Age, @Height)", Connection))
                    try
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idPlayers", idPlayers);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", Surname);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Age);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", Height);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Connection.Close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        result = ex.Message;
                        return result;
                    }                    
            }
        result = "Success";
        return result;  
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Why are you ignoring the exception in your `catch` block?  I guarantee that exception is telling you *exactly* what's wrong.  Ignoring errors won't help you fix things.

Comment: @David is correct, instead of failure, track the error message and post that here. That will be a lot more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First problem**, parameter names (well, identifier in general) can't have spaces in the query:

```
"... VALUES(@idPlayers, @First Name, @Surname, @Age, @Height)"
```

The query engine has no way to interpret `@First Name`.  Make it a single word:

```
"... VALUES(@idPlayers, @FirstName, @Surname, @Age, @Height)"
```

*Edit:* Related to this, you're also using a space in another identifier:

```
"INSERT INTO Players(idPlayers, First Name, Surname, Age, Height) ..."
```

Same problem, you can't use spaces like this.  I *highly* recommend not using spaces in column/table names.  But if you *must*, then you'll need to enclose their identifiers to reference them in queries.  If I remember correctly, MySQL uses back-ticks for this:

```
"INSERT INTO Players(idPlayers, `First Name`, Surname, Age, Height) ..."
```

**Second problem**, you're not adding the parameters correctly:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("idPlayers", idPlayers);
```

You don't have a parameter called `idPlayers`, you have one called `@idPlayers`.  There's a difference.  Try this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idPlayers", idPlayers);
```

**Biggest problem**, you're ignoring exceptions.  Don't ignore error messages, they tell you *exactly* what's wrong.  You should be examining that exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // "ex" contains the error information you're looking for
    // log it, show it to the user, do something with it
}
```

Comment: @GeorgeSillett: Looks like you had two instances of the first problem, I've updated my answer to point out the other one.

Comment: Using back-ticks with the space did not work but I removed the space from the column name in my table and now it all works perfectly. Thanks so much for your time! :)